# Implementing Binary Classification for LSTM and Linear Layer Output

Tags: python, pytorch, lstm, tensor

I'm working on developing a wake word model for my AI assistant. My model architecture includes an LSTM layer to process audio data, followed by a Linear Layer. However, I'm encountering an unexpected output shape from the Linear Layer, which is causing confusion.

After passing the LSTM output (shape: 4, 32, 32) to the Linear Layer, I expected an output shape of (4, 32, 1). However, the actual output shape is (4, 32, 1).

In my binary classification task, I aim to distinguish between two classes: 0 for "do not wake up" and 1 for "wake up the AI." My batch size is 32, and I anticipated the output to be in the shape (32, 1) to represent one prediction for each audio MFCC input.

Could someone advise on the correct configuration of the Linear Layer or any processing steps needed to achieve the desired output shape of (32, 1)? Any insights or code examples would be greatly appreciated. Below is my model code for reference:

```py
class LSTMWakeWord(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self,input_size,hidden_size,num_layers,dropout,bidirectional,num_of_classes, device='cpu'):
        super(LSTMWakeWord, self).__init__()
        self.input_size = input_size
        self.hidden_size = hidden_size
        self.num_layers = num_layers
        self.device = device
        self.bidirectional = bidirectional
        self.directions = 2 if bidirectional else 1

        self.lstm = nn.LSTM(input_size=input_size,
                            hidden_size = hidden_size,
                            num_layers = num_layers,
                            dropout=dropout,
                            bidirectional=bidirectional,
                            batch_first=True)
        self.layernorm = nn.LayerNorm(input_size)

        self.classifier = nn.Linear(hidden_size , num_of_classes)

    def _init_hidden(self,batch_size):
        n, d, hs = self.num_layers, self.directions, self.hidden_size
        return (torch.zeros(n * d, batch_size, hs).to(self.device),
                torch.zeros(n * d, batch_size, hs).to(self.device))

    def forward(self,x):
        # the values with e+xxx are gone. so it normalizes the values
        x = self.layernorm(x)
        # x shape ->  feature(n_mfcc),batch,seq_len(time)
        hidden = self._init_hidden(x.size()[0])
        out, (hn, cn) = self.lstm(x, hidden)
        print("hn "+str(hn.shape))# directions∗num_layers, batch, hidden_size
        #print("out " + str(out.shape))# batch, seq_len, direction(2 or 1)*hidden_size
        out = self.classifier(hn)
        print("out2 " + str(out.shape))

        return out
```

I'd greatly appreciate any insights or guidance on how to handle the Linear Layer output for binary classification.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```py
hn = hn[-1, :, :]
out = self.classifier(hn)
```

Comment: thanks but i don't like to copy paste without understanding what's going on. Could you please explain after the (4,32,32) goes into linear and gets out as (4,32,1) , What does that mean? i mean i gave 32 audio mfcc's and i should have a single prediction for each one right? but i have 4 times more. so how can i know which one refers the actual audio or how should i understand this?

Comment: You get hn as (4 32 32), which means the number of layers is 4(if directions=1), the batch size is 32, and the hidden size is 32. hn contains the output of the last hidden element of each layer, you need to take the last layer, which is (32 32). Then you feed it into nn.Linear(hidden_size , num_of_classes=2) and you get a (32 2) tensor with two probability values per row. I don't know if the above statement is correct, but I do understand it that way. My English is not good, I hope to help you!

Comment: That's what i wanted to hear. Now it is all clear thank you !